# Persistent static routes are lost after Windows 10 updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, static-routes

After each Windows 10 update and after rebooting our corporate computers some of the static routes are lost.
Of course they are defined as persistent and if you list them with "route print" they are there, however at least one of them stops working. This happens in different computers and with different routes so is not computer related nor route related.

The only solution we found so far is to delete the failing route and create it again.

Did you experience a similar problem? Could you give us a clue about what may be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you creating these routes in your actual router(s)?

Answer (score -2):

For me it's not after each reboot but very often the route is show when i do a route print, but still like disable.

I have to route delete, and route add xxxxx -P to remake it Permanent.

The route is ok and connexion is up. But very randomly the route seem to be crashed. I have to re make the command again and again and again.

In my opinion, i'll write a script route.bat on each windows startup -> do a route delete + route add.

Thx Microsoft ..

Comment: for information, it's not located on one computer only, it's in a parc of 2 thousands more / less computers located in europe / outside europe, randomly only on windows 10 installs.